# How to talk to manager to assign a task to someone else

Tags: communication, management, manager, negotiation, task-management

I am working on a task at a software company for two weeks. Now I realize that one of the team members who guide me is too slow or confusing. I am unable to make much progress after a certain amount of work and have been circling.
I am getting frustrated about the current task. Whenever I contact my fellow senior member to guide me, she always connects but we don't hit a concrete end.
For this reason, I want to tell my manager that the task is 70% done so assign it to someone else from here.  Instead of getting bogged down with the current one, I will have more time to work on other tasks.

Answer (score 19):

That is almost entirely the wrong way to approach this. You don't decide who does which tasks, your manager (or team lead etc) does. So what should you do?

Talk to your manager, explain the problem - that you are having difficulties communicating with your colleague - and *ask them* what they would you like you to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the other answer. If you've got difficulties completing the task you should ask your senior fellow first what you should do about it and later maybe also whether it's OK for him if you asked the manager if someone else could take it over.

Talking to the manager right away behind the back of the senior colleague might be taken not nicely by them. They could even think you've reported their failure to help you with the task and I pretty sure you don't want anyone to take it that way.

Comment: That wasn't what my answer was meant to imply: I wasn't suggesting that the OP doesn't talk to his co-worker, just that when they talk to their manager, they don't demand the task is given to someone else.